# bind laravel app authentican to another laravel app authentican

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have two laravel app and each has separate authentication (login), now what I want is when the user successfully login to my first laravel app (login laravel app) then the second laravel app (serve as the main app) will authenticate the current logged user (successfully login). It's some sort of a global authentication where I have single separate login laravel app to be used in login and once use has logged in to that laravel app then he can automatically logged to any other app that was bind to that login app. Any ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations, help please?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I know this may not sound helpful, but there are lots of different ways this could be done, so it largely comes down to what your requirements/constraints are.

Things to think about:

- How are your sessions currently managed?
- Does there need to be a seamless transition or is it acceptable to log out users when the new system is in place?
- Do you have the time and resources to implement a future-proofed solution or are you looking for a quick fix?
- Do you have a roadmap for future development that might influence your implementation now?

This list is by no means exhaustive!

The answer is hiding somewhere in those questions but it is difficult to propose a true solution without more information. Think through the problem and the solution should present itself.

Comment: +1 The trick is informing app2 that the user has already logged in to app1 in a way that is secure. And that depends heavily on a lot of details that are not given in your questions.

Comment: yes, @Kryten, thats what I want, inform the app2 that user has already logged in to app1 in a way that is secure.